# ASP.NET speed up handling of results from async requests

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I just recently converted my websites requests to async, it goes about thrice the speed before, but I discovered a drawback. Let me explain, I use 20 different request towards a page. When page is loaded I parse the results, and add them to a dictionary, when this is done I check the dictionary for they key I provided an I get information on wether the information was found or not.

Now before async this took about 30 secs when running all 20 request. Today I'm running 20 request at about 7 seconds, great improvment, but.... If the old method found the information in the first request, it finished in under 2 seconds. Using this method it always takes 7 seconds.

How should I do to, finish of everything right when the information is found? Instead of doing all twenty requests. This is the code.

EDIT I TRIED TO REMOVE THE WAITALL, BUT THAT GAVE ME WORSE PERFORMANCE.

```
public decimal GetWebpage(string urltovisit, string visitorurl, string information)
    {
        List<HtmlDocument> htmllist = new List<HtmlDocument>();
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
        FetchPageDelegate del = new FetchPageDelegate(FetchPage);
        List<IAsyncResult> results = new List<IAsyncResult>();
        List<WaitHandle> waitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>();
        _visitorUrl = visitorurl;
        _theSearchedinformation = information;

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i += 10)
        {
            string url = urltovisit + i;
            IAsyncResult result = del.BeginInvoke(url, null, null);
            results.Add(result);
            waitHandles.Add(result.AsyncWaitHandle);
        }

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());

        foreach (IAsyncResult async in results)
        {
            FetchPageDelegate pagedelagate = (async as AsyncResult).AsyncDelegate as FetchPageDelegate;
            //THIS FUNCTION PARSES AND ADDS THE RESULT TO A DICTIONARY
            DocParser.StartParse(pagedelagate.EndInvoke(async));

            if (GetPostion() != 201)
            {   //ADD DATA TO DATABASE
                InsertRankingData(DocParser.GetSearchResults(), _theSearchedinformation);
                return GetPostion();
            }

        }
        return 201;
      }
```

So should I create a new list of delagates to run the method and class that parses and adds to the dictionary? Or can I use the waithandles to tell that result has been found? Im really clueless here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use undone handlers collection and return flag.

```
var done=false
var index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles.ToArray());
while(!done)
{
  var async=waitHandles.ElementAt(index);
  WaitHandle.RemoveAt(index);
  FetchPageDelegate pagedelagate = (async as AsyncResult).AsyncDelegate as FetchPageDelegate;

  // change done flag

}
```

But it's more comfortable use Wintellect Power Threading